# Compare order of elements in two arrays

Tags: php

I need PHP function to compare order of elements in two arrays. First array is standard which saves correct order, the second is array to compare.

1. Elements in array to compare can be repeated.
2. Array to compare can contain not all elements that are in etalon array.

Example:

```
<?php
    // Standard
    $standard = array(
        'taxonomy',
        'post_meta',
        'author',
        'date',
        'post_meta_num'
    );
    
    // Valid order
    $valid_order = array(
        'taxonomy',
        'taxonomy',
        'post_meta',
        'date'
    );
    
    // Invalid order, 'author' is before 'post_meta'
    $invalid_order = array(
        'taxonomy',
        'author',
        'author',
        'post_meta'
    );
?>
```

I tried to find something on StackOverflow, but already existing answers are not compatible with my task. This function works correctly only if array to compare contains all elements from standard.

```
<?php
    function compare( $standard, $to_compare  ){
        if( ! is_array( $standard ) || ! is_array( $to_compare ) ){
            return false;
        }
    
        $i = 0;
    
        foreach ( $to_compare as $value ) {
            if( $value === $standard[$i] ){
                $i++;
            }
        }
    
        return ( $i == count( $standard ) );
    }
?>
```

In the end the function should return true if order in standard and array to compare is equal and false if is not equal.
Thank you.

Comment: if I really understand, the correct order that should be considered is in the $etalon array.

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI yes, you are absolutely right.

Comment: @Stepasyuk, could you show us what have you tried? The questions showing no effort from the OP's side are not welcome on SO.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov sorry, I'm really noobie here. I already provided my question with example I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there can be no boolean values in the arrays, you can do the following:

```php
<?php
/**
 * @param string[] $standard
 * @param string[] $to_compare
 * @return bool
 */
function compare(array $standard, array $to_compare) : bool {
    $standard_item = reset($standard);

    foreach ($to_compare as $item) {
        // Skip standard items assuming they are all optional
        while ($item !== $standard_item) {
            $standard_item = next($standard);
            if ($standard_item === false) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if ($standard_item === false || $item !== $standard_item) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you want to support `false` values in the standard array, the code above might be modified so that the the items are referred to by indices, e.g. `$standard[$i]`. But this approach has its drawback as well -- the keys must be numeric and sequential. For a more generic solution I would probably use an iterator such as `ArrayIterator`.

Answer (score 0):

you want to use `usort()`
https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.usort.php

it would look something like

```
function custom_sort(&$my_array) {
    return usort($my_array, function ($a, $b) {
        global $etalon;
        $a_key = array_search($a, $etalon);
        $b_key = array_search($b, $etalon);
        if (($a_key === FALSE) || ($b_key === FALSE) || ($a_key == $b_key)) {
            return 0;
        }
        ($a_key < $b_key) ? -1 : 1;
    });
}

custom_sort($valid_order);
custom_sort($invalid_order)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that can help :

```
 // Etalon
    $etalon = array(
        'taxonomy',
        'post_meta',
        'author',
        'date',
        'post_meta_num'
    );
    
    // Valid order
    $valid_order = array(
        'taxonomy',
        'taxonomy',
        'post_meta',
        'date'
    );
    
    // Invalid order, 'author' is before 'post_meta'
    $invalid_order = array(
        'taxonomy',
        'author',
        'author',
        'post_meta'
    );
    

function checkOrder($array , $etalon)
{
    $array = array_values(array_unique($array));
    $array = array_intersect($array, $etalon );
    
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        if(!in_array($array[$key],$etalon) || array_search($array[$key], $etalon)<$key){
          return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


var_dump(checkOrder($valid_order,$etalon)); // true

var_dump(checkOrder($invalid_order,$etalon)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution which I find easy to follow:

```
class Transition
{
    private string $fromValue;
    private array $toValues;

    public function __construct(string $fromValue, array $toValues)
    {
        $this->fromValue = $fromValue;
        $this->toValues = $toValues;
    }

    public function getFromValue(): string
    {
        return $this->fromValue;
    }

    public function getToValues(): array
    {
        return $this->toValues;
    }
}

function prepareTransitionsMap(array $orderDefinitions): array
{
    $transitions = [];
    $definitionsCount = count($orderDefinitions);
    foreach ($orderDefinitions as $i => $fromValue) {
        $toValues = [];
        for ($j = $i; $j < $definitionsCount; ++$j) {
            $toValues[] = $orderDefinitions[$j];
        }

        $transitions[$fromValue] = new Transition($fromValue, $toValues);
    }

    return $transitions;
}

function isArrayOrderValid(array $orderDefinitions, array $valuesToCheck): bool
{
    $valuesCount = count($valuesToCheck);
    if ($valuesCount === 0) {
        return true;
    }

    $definitionsCount = count($orderDefinitions);
    if ($definitionsCount === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    $transitionsMap = prepareTransitionsMap($orderDefinitions);
    foreach ($valuesToCheck as $i => $iValue) {
        $valueToCheck = $iValue;

        // value is no defined at all
        if (!array_key_exists($valueToCheck, $transitionsMap)) {
            return false;
        }

        // value is the last in the array
        if (!array_key_exists($i + 1, $valuesToCheck)) {
            return true;
        }

        $nextValue = $valuesToCheck[$i + 1];
        $transition = $transitionsMap[$valueToCheck];

        if (!in_array($nextValue, $transition->getToValues(), true)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

isArrayOrderValid($standard, $valid_order); // true
isArrayOrderValid($standard, $invalid_order); // false
```